# Scheduling jobs in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, scheduler, telegram

I want to create an ASP.MVC App with which I want to send some messages to my telegram channel via `Telegram Bot Api` at a certain time automatically, even when I am not in my web app.

For example I want to send one of my messages on these dates: 2018/03/23, 2018/03/28, 2018/04/05.

I want to send these messages without any human help and automatically
but I do not know how to do it. Now I can send my message at this time, not at the later time and automatically.

Comment: You need to write a service. The Telegram.Bot api you could write as a WebAPI and have it hosted in IIS. You then write a windows service to Call the API and send the info specified. Depending on the data that you want to send you can place it in a DB or file and simply get your windows service to read it.

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Overflow! Please, [search and research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch) before asking. Also, you could read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article to improve your chances of getting an useful answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [HangFire](https://www.hangfire.io/) which is available as nuget packages and may suit your needs perfectly.

> An easy way to perform background processing in .NET and .NET Core applications. No Windows Service or separate process required.
>   Backed by persistent storage. Open and free for commercial use.

Which allows to create :

> Delayed jobs are executed only once too, but not immediately, after a certain time interval.

```
var jobId = BackgroundJob.Schedule(
    () => Console.WriteLine("Delayed!"),
    TimeSpan.FromDays(7));
```

Answer (score 0):

With .Net native there is no such option available (at least I am not aware of it).

Either create a windows service which is monitoring the database and performing the operations.

Or, a little bit more simple, create a scheduled task which is running every 5 minutes eg. and executing a console application.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19205667)

Comment: @Tjaart, sorry but I do not understand why this is not an answer. It is not possible, you could workaround with following 2 solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to implement the same into Asp.Net MVC..? In MVC you can't shedule the task, still if you can but it not proper way of implementation.

As per your requirement you should have to go with windows service, this will be a perfect approach for your requirement implementation.